# Use html 4.01 to markup this layout of table,using table element

Tags: html, html-table

[image]

Can anyone please teach me how to markup this table in HTML using only table and NO EXTERNAL CSS, just use the simplest attribute of table element

- use just plain HTML only
- the size are stated
- the border,cell spacing and padding can be ignore
- total width=800 and height=600

Can anyon help?

Comment: How do you imagine your table when your last row's width does not correspond to the width of the rows above? IMHO that is not possible

Comment: I agree with @caligula - the only way that you can make this table is if you adjust the bottom row to match the width, then you can do that.

Comment: the last rom , 2nd cell should be 300X250 ,sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you should use two tables, but i don't think that is good idea. Try something like this:

```
<TABLE border="1" Width="800" Height="200" Align="Center">
<TR>
    <TD Width="400" Height="200">1 
    <TD Width="400" Height="200">2
</TR>
</TABLE>

<TABLE border="1" Width="800" Height="400" Align="Center">
<TR>
    <TD colspan="3" Width="800" Height="200">3
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD Width="250" Height="200">4 
    <TD Width="300" Height="200">5 
    <TD Width="250" Height="200">6
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: sorry , the picture was incorrect , now already corrected , can you please show me the way using a single table